# Chromium Browser not opening

Tags: chromium

Whenever I try to open chromium from the desktop, I get a loading cursor, then nothing happens. I tried to start it from terminal to see what the problem was, and it returned this error:

```
[
1:1:1112/112537:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_client.cc(126)] Check failed: IsFileSystemAccessDenied(). 
#0 0x000055435098 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x00005544a87c logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x000058044e50 sandbox::SetuidSandboxClient::ChrootMe()
#3 0x000057d81aa4 content::ZygoteMain()
#4 0x0000553fed4c content::RunZygote()
#5 0x000055400300 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
#6 0x0000553feacc content::ContentMain()
#7 0x000054f58a1c ChromeMain
#8 0x000075ba2294 __libc_start_main

Received signal 6
#0 0x000055435098 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x000055434fe8 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#2 0x000075bb91a0 <unknown>
#3 0x000075bb7f70 gsignal
[end of stack trace]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to re-install it to avoid any corruption in its files:

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: Before installing chromium-browser again it would be a good advice to `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and reboot if you have a lot of updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rename chrome folder ,inside /home/your_user/.config/  , as backup and try to open browser . Automatically it creates a new one folder. It has been working for me when upgrades or updates break configs .

Comment: Didn't work. Returned the same stack trace as before.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Chromium running on a Zero W using the Buster Legacy OS, 2023-02-21 release (Version 3.6 January 2021).

But... I had to install with default pi user account (different password).  It didn't work if I installed the image with a different user account name, admin.

Manually installed Chromium using
sudo apt install chromium-browser

I couldn't get Chromium to run in Bullseye on RPi0W.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously been using Chromium on your raspberry pi but are suddenly unable to get it to run, it's most likely that Chromium did not close properly. Head to /home/user/config/chromium/ and delete the files 'SingletonCookie' 'SingletonLock' and SingletonSocket (red triangle! icons). Chromium will open now and you haven't lost any settings, extensions or other data.